# Show jAlert message triggerd in iframe a in iframe b

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I do use iframes to show two pages in one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my.css">
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="static" src="static.php"></iframe>
<iframe id="main" name="main" src="login.php"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The static PHP page is always shown up and will be changed using JavaScript.

The main iframe use 98% of the monitor height and the static iframe use only 2%.

I use the jQuery Alerts Plugin to show nice alert boxes with messages. Now I want to show triggered messages by the static box in the main frame. But the normal way will not work.

The message box is called by using this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">jAlert('Message','Warning');</script>
```

jAlert uses `$("BODY").append` to show the message box. I tried to replace `$("BODY")` with `$("#main").contents().find("body")` to use always the main frame. But this did not show up a message box.

How can I always use the BODY of the iframe main page?